# Except query in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I would like to exclude certain data from a request

Ideally, it would look something like this

```
Model::where('firstname', 'like', '%$firstname%')
   ->exceptWhere('lastname, 'like', '%$lastname%');
```

We want to load all data where condition A is true,
But exclude results that match condition B.

We must use the `like` or `not like` syntax.

For our program, we are dealing with big data. We cannot use `whereIn` as SQL has a limit of 65,000 placeholders. Therefore, we must select the correct data in a query.

How can I do this in Laravel or raw SQL? We are getting an error that `exclude` keyword is not available in MySQL 5.4.

We have also tried a few variants, which did not work, eg

```
WHERE (condition A)
AND NOT (condition B)
```

However, I can get the correct results using Sequel Pro GUI, using `contains` and `does not contain` but I cannot get the same results using SQL / Eloquent.

Comment: Have you tried `->where('lastname, 'not like', '%$lastname%');`?

Comment: Yes, it only returns those results not like condition A. It does not filter them out. We need to exclude B from A.

Comment: have you tried `where('lastname, '!=', '%$lastname%');` ?

Comment: Please describe what result you want.
I have understood that you want all users with a firstname including the given firstname but without the ones with a lastname including the given lastname. Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, we want to include condition A, but exclude any results that match condition B.

Comment: I'm really surprised that it didn't worked then.

Could you provide the raw sql generated ? (with `dd(Model::query()->where('firstname', 'like', '%$firstname%')->where('lastname', 'not like', '%$lastname%')->toSql());`)

Comment: `Model::where('firstname', 'like', '%$firstname%')->where('lastname', 'not like', '%$lastname%');` will return from A that is not like B. It does not filter B from A. ```select * from `users` where `firstname` like ? and `lastname` not like ?```

Comment: I'm sorry, could you rephrase "A that is not like B" and "filter B from A" I don't understand the difference.

Comment: In your query, We get all results from A, and we then from that query, we get all results from A that are not like B. It does not exclude B from A.

Comment: @Dazzle check my latest code it will work i have tested that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `whereNotExists()`

```php
Model::where('firstname', 'LIKE', "%$firstname%")
    ->whereNotExists(function ($q) use ($lastname) {
        $q->where('lastname', 'like', "%$lastname%");
    })->get();
return view('home');
```

it will generate SQL like

```sql
select * from `models` where `firstname` LIKE ? and not exists (select * where `lastname` like ?)
```

ref link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html